# PHP SESSION ARRAY overwritten by post variable

Tags: php, arrays, session

I am trying to save data from a post to my array session variable. But instead of adding new element it overwrites the old one... What am I doing wrong ?

```
//PHP CODE !!!
$_SESSION['file[]'] = $_FILES['file'];
$_SESSION['file_names[]'] = $_POST['file_name'];
print_r($_SESSION['file[]']); //it will only display last selected file. :(

//HTML !!!
<form method="post" action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <input type="input" name="file_name" value="">
   <input type="file" name="file" id="file" value="">
   <input type="submit" name="SEND" value="ADD"/>
</form>

//LITLE CHECK CODE HERE !!!
//THIS CODE WILL DISPLAY " OUT OF IF STATEMENT !!!" ;/

<?php
    if(isset($_SESSION['file_names[]']) && is_array($_SESSION['file_names[]'])){
        foreach($_SESSION['file_names[]'] as $index => $name){
                     /...
        }
    }else{
        echo " OUT OF IF STATEMENT !!!"; //executed!
    }
?>
```

Any ide ?

Comment: you cannot store arrays in session variables like that way, you have to use seperate session variables to each array element...
$_SESSION['file_names[]'] means just one variable named 'file_name[]'

Comment: *sidenote:* is that a typo that you close a form tag with an `<form>`?

Comment: yes it is typo :> its ok in my source code i will correct this now. Thx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i think you want to make the `$_SESSION` multi dimensional array, so change:

```
$_SESSION['file[]'] = $_FILES['file'];
$_SESSION['file_names[]'] = $_POST['file_name'];
```

to

```
$_SESSION['file'][] = $_FILES['file']; //assign $_FILES data to session array
$_SESSION['file_names'][] = $_POST['file_name']; //assign $_POST data to session array
print_r($_SESSION['file']);
```

Comment: let me try this brb ! And I am back now :)  Love you Sudhir. Works like a charm ! :>